# When uploading images to AWS S3 bad request 400 error is thrown on browser console. How to upload images on S3 without any error?

Tags: php, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

When I upload photo error is thrown that Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request).

Access key and the Secret key is correct. Also, the name of the bucket is mentioned right.

**CORS are mentioned below:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Also used crossdomain.xml in bucket

```
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Code files are uploaded on EC2.

How to remove this 400 Bad request error?

Using s3.php for the purpose.

Comment: check if you are uploading at the right region

Comment: @SayantanDas Yes, the region used is correct.

Comment: you should be receiving some error response, can you include that too with your question?

Comment: check the error body

Comment: @DileepKumar error is POST https://abcd.s3.amazonaws.com/ 400 (Bad Request) on browser console.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html